# SQL class code is injected

Tags: php, xss

I am working on DB class, while testing, I found that the code is injected, I added a small JS script into field1, and this is the result:

[image]

```
<?php


final class crud {

private $connexionName, $sql = '';

public function __construct($connexionName) {

    $this->connexionName  = $connexionName;
}


public final function insert($tableName, $fields=array()){

        $this->tableName = $tableName;
        $this->fields    = $fields;


        foreach ($this->fields as $vf) {

            $inKeys[]       = $vf;
            $inKeysDotted[] = ':' . $vf;


            $insImKeys       = implode(', ', $inKeys);
            $insImKeysDotted = implode(', ', $inKeysDotted);


            $this->insImKeys         = $insImKeys;
            $this->insImKeysDotted   = $insImKeysDotted;

        }

            $this->insertedKeys         = $inKeys;
            $this->insertedKeysDotted   = $inKeysDotted;


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->tableName` ($this->insImKeys) VALUES ($this->insImKeysDotted);";
        //echo $sql.'<br />';

        $insertItems = $this->connexionName->prepare($sql);

        $this->insertItems    = $insertItems;

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($insertItems).'<br />';
        echo '</pre>';

} // end prepareStm()

public final function checkValType($valToCheck){

    $this->valToCheck     = $valToCheck;

    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php
    $valType = gettype($this->valToCheck);

    $this->valType    = $valType;

    switch ($this->valType) {
        case 'boolean':
            $PDOType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;

        case 'integer':
            $PDOType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;

        case 'NULL':
            $PDOType = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;

        default: // string
            $PDOType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            break;
    }

    //echo $PDOType.'<br />';

    $this->PDOType    = $PDOType;
    //return $this->valType;
    return $this->PDOType;

} // end checkValType()


public final function bindParams($setValues=array()){


    $combine = array_combine($this->insertedKeys, $setValues);

    foreach ($combine as $getKey => $getVal) {

        $setType    = $this->checkValType($getVal);


   echo "this->insertItems->bindValue($getKey, $getVal, $setType)<br />";
   $this->insertItems->bindValue($getKey, $getVal, $setType);


    }


} // end bindParams()


public final function executeQuery(){
    return $this->insertItems->execute();
}



}

require_once '../Included_Files/Connect.php';



$con = new crud($connexion);

echo '<br />';

$con->insert('test', array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'));
//$con->checkValType(19);
$con->bindParams(array('<script>alert(\'hello\');</script>', 'pour field2', 'pour field3'));
$con->executeQuery();
```

?>

How can I avoid these kind of injections?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: well, basically, I used bindParam, and while inserting, it remove the scripts tags

Comment: Bear in mind that on the way into the database - you are concerned with SQL injection (with this not being SQL). It is on the output that you would then filter this to stop XSS (the rule is called "filter input, escape output". This is therefore not an injection. If you wanted to clean this on the way in use php striptags().

Comment: That's correct, it is XSS attack, sorry I got confused, I used trim and strip_tags functions, so I can end up with no SQL injection danger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> well, basically, I used bindParam, and while inserting, it remove the
>   scripts tags

Your assumption is wrong. You have JavaScript embedded in HTML, which in turn is embedded in SQL. Each of those languages have different escaping schemes, and pose different risks. `bindParam` deals only with SQL injection, i.e. the outermost layer. It does not deal with escaping HTML, removing `<script>` tags, and that's good.

So the bottom line is: there's no SQL injection vulnerability in your code. Your application may or may not be vulnerable to XSS or other exploits, but that's beyond scope of SQL injection.

Comment: That's correct, it is XSS attack, is my code vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: No, your code is not vulnerable to SQL injection. SQL injection happens when user submits strings like `something'; DROP TABLE \`test\`; --` that get interpolated in SQL query.